# Spring Boot JPA Query modify dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

Using Spring boot,I am working on one business use case where i need to modify the JPA query generated at runtime based on configuration.

For Example .. if query that JPA generates is

```
select * from customers where id=1234
```

I want to modify it in runtime like based on user's logged in context. (Context has one attribute business unit) like given below ..

```
select * from customers where id=1234 and ***business_unit='BU001'***
```

Due to certain business use case restrictions i can't have statically typed query.

Using Spring boot and Postgres SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try **JPA criteria builder** , it let you to create dynamics query programmatically.

Take look in [this post](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries)

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you to extract the business unit from the context and pass it to the query?

If you have this Entity

```
@Entity
CustomerEntity {
  Long id;
  String businessUnit;
  //geters + setters
}
```

you can add this query to your JPA Repository interface:

```
CustomerEntity findByIdAndBusinessUnit(Long id, String businessUnit)
```

This will generate the following `"where"` clause:

```
… where x.id=?1 and x.businessUnit=?2
```

for complete documentation check [Spring Data Jpa Query creation guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation).

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like this, this lets you dynamically define additional predicates you need in your query. **if you don't want to have all the conditions in your query with `@Query`**

The below example just adds a single predicate.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Root;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import study.spring.data.jpa.models.TicketPrice;

@Component
public class TricketPriceCriteriaRepository {
    @Autowired
    TicketPriceJpaRepository ticketPriceJpaRepository;

    public List<TicketPrice> findByCriteria(int price) {
        return ticketPriceJpaRepository.findAll(new Specification<TicketPrice>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<TicketPrice> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query,
                    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
                List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
                if (price > 0) {
                    predicates.add(
                            criteriaBuilder.and(criteriaBuilder.greaterThan(root.get("basePrice"), price)));
                }
                // Add other predicates here based on your inputs 
                // Your session based predicate
                return criteriaBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Your base repository would be like

```
// Other imports
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;

public interface TicketPriceJpaRepository
        extends JpaRepository<TicketPrice, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<TicketPrice> {}
```

the model consists basePrice

```
@Column(name = "base_price")
private BigDecimal basePrice;
```